# UITableView unwanted white space when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I created a simple UItTableView.The ScreenShot is as follows.

[image]

I have created TableView as a programmatic.

```
var appearingWifiTableView: UITableView = {
    var tempTableView = UITableView()
    tempTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 46, green: 54, blue: 57)
    return tempTableView
}()

override func setupViews() {
    addSubview(appearingWifiTableView)
}
```

But when I scroll upwards:

[image]

When I make a scroll down

[image]

How to get rid of unwanted white spaces seen in pictures?If this is not possible how do I change the white background to another color?

Comment: either disable bounce or set your tableview background color to the same as your cell.

Comment: I can change the color with your suggestion, but still scrolling to the offset area.(tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false not working)

Comment: disable bounce by tempTableView.bounces = false

Comment: @QweQwe, try to set the same background color for the view that contains tableView as well.

Comment: @koropok tempTableView.bounces = false => works.If you answer the question, I can mark it as the correct answer, after 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can either set the table view color to the same as your cell, or disable bounce by:

```
tempTableView.bounces = false
```

Answer (score 0):

set `tableview.backgroundcolor = UIColor.clear`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to scroll effect in the top , you can use

`tableView.bounces = false`

Or If you want to change white color , you can use

```
tableView.backgroundcolor = UIColor.yourColor
```